# How to create a date field and set it to current date minus n hours

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I need to add to some documents a new date field which value needs to be set to the current date minus 1 hour .

This change needs to be applied to all the documents which contain this field-value pair: *"ext_lms_identifier" : "PREVIEW"*

I'm trying something like:

```
db.zips.updateMany({"city":"ALPINE"}, {$set:{"ttl_date": new ISODate(new Date() - 1000*60*60*24)}})
```

This doesn't work but I need something like this, so i can initialize a date with the result of the current date minus one day.

How can I achieve this with a script?

Comment: Please provide some sample input document and desired output. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal by doing this:

```
db.zips.updateMany({"city":"ALPINE"}, {$set:{"ttl_date": new Date(Date.now()-1000*60*60)}})
```